# Given $f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-10)$ what is the derivative $f'(0)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R; x \mapsto f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-10)$$
>   Evaluate $f'(0)$!

I've tried to set the factors apart, but I only know that $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$.
I don't know how I should apply that rule for any $n$ amount of factors. I also thought of actually doing the multiplication, but I don't know what shortcut I should use, and multiplicating one after the other takes extremely long.

Comment: look at the edited text to see how to make your equations looks nice

Comment: Do you want $f^{\prime}(0)$ factorial, or are you just very excited about $f^{\prime}(0)$?

Comment: @Surb thanks, I'll take a look at it!

I think Jack gave me the perfect answer below, thanks!

Comment: Another method: logarithmic differentiation.

Comment: 10!! looks like a super awesome number

Comment: let $P(x) = (x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-n)$, it is clear that $P(x)$ is differentiable and $P(0) = (-1)^n n!$, so that $f(x) = x P(x) \implies f'(x) = P(x)+x P'(x) \implies f'(0) = P(0) = (-1)^n n!$

Comment: Ohh, I feel so ashamed, but it took me this long, to understand this whole thing!
Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x) = x$ and $h(x) = (x-1)\cdots (x-10)$. Then $f'(x) = g(x) h'(x) + g'(x)h(x)$. Since $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1$, we have
$$f'(0) = h(0) = (-1)(-2)\cdots (-10) = 10!$$

Comment: Your answer was the most intuitive for me, thank you! It's the simplest IMO and I've only begun calculus :)

Answer (score 11):

Apply the definition:
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=
\lim_{x\to0}\,(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-10)=10!
$$
More generally, if $f(x)=x(x-1)\dots(x-n)$, the same argument shows
$$
f'(0)=(-1)^n\cdot n!
$$

Comment: Interestingly, the definition of the derivative is useful at times!

Comment: @Wojowu Who might have suspected it? `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** A polynomial is always an entire function, and in a neighbourhood of the origin:
$$ x(x-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-10) = 10!\,x+O(x^2) $$
hence
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left. x(x-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-10)\right|_{x=0} = \color{red}{10!}. $$

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Math SE. To format your question you can use LaTeX.

Now coming to your question, the derivative of a product is just the sum of the $n$ products where only one of the members is differentiated. In your case

$((x)... (x-10))' = [(x-1)...(x-10)]+[x(x-2)...(x-10)]+...+[x(x-1)...(x-9)]$

Note that all but the first expression will evaluate to $0$ at $x=0$ since you're multiplying by 0 ($x$) so $f'(0)=(-1)(-2)...(-10)=10!$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
However, I don't fully understand this part, unfortunately:
$((x)... (x-10))' = [(x-1)...(x-10)]+[x(x-2)...(x-10)]+...+[x(x-1)...(x-9)]$

How does this work exactly?

Comment: @bertalanp99 Try it by hand with just three terms. Differentiate $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ using the product rule (twice).  The form should pop out.  Your question just adds more terms in the product.

Answer (score 1):

There is an $n$-term version of the product rule that is definitely worth knowing about.  You'll see the pattern from the $n = 3$ case.  If $f(x) = f_1(x) f_2(x) f_3(x)$, then
\begin{equation}
f'(x) = f_1'(x) f_2(x) f_3(x) + f_1(x) f_2'(x) f_3(x) + f_1(x) f_2(x) f_3'(x).
\end{equation}
(Do you see what the formula would be for a product of four functions?)

In your case, $f'(x)$ is a sum of $11$ terms, and all but one of those terms vanish when you plug in $x = 0$.

Richard Feynman made a big deal about the usefulness of this $n$-term product rule in The Feynman Tips on Physics.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if
$f(x)
=\prod_{k=1}^n (x-a_k)^{b_k}
$,
then
$\ln f(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \ln(x-a_k)
$.

Differentiating,
$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{b_k}{x-a_k}
$,
so
$f'(x)
=f(x)\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{b_k}{x-a_k}
$.

Setting $x=0$,

$\begin{array}\\
f'(0)
&=f(0)\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{b_k}{-a_k}\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^n (-a_j)^{b_j}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{b_k}{-a_k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k(-a_k)^{b_k-1}\prod_{j=1, j \ne k}^n (-a_j)^{b_j}\\
\end{array}
$

If $a_k = k-1$
and $b_k = 1$
as in your case,

$\begin{array}\\
f'(0)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{j=1, j \ne k}^n (-j+1)\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{j=1, j \ne k}^n (j-1)\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\left(\prod_{j=2}^n (j-1)+\sum_{k=2}^n \prod_{j=1, j \ne k}^n (j-1)\right)\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!
\qquad\text{since all terms with }k\ge 2 \text{ have j=1 so are zero}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this answer must be a deep mistery. It is correct, it gives the correct answer in the particular case asked by the OP and also, for whoever is interested, it gives a nice though slightly abstract development to deal with these things. And anyone aspiring to cope with mathematics at *any level* above $\;2\cdot2=4\;$ cannot get scared of a little abstraction. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not the downvoter. The answer glosses over two facts: the first is that taking the logarithm is not really possible (but it's a formal method, so nothing really bad if we know what we're doing). However, the computation is done assuming $a_k\ne0$; it can easily be adjusted, though, with doing a limit or some simpler trick.

Comment: @egreg You're right, indeed. +1

Comment: In my answer, I separated out the case $a_k = 0$ in the first term; this caused all the other terms to vanish at $x = 0$.